# What is meant by the notation ||x, y||?

Tags: notation, fluid-dynamics

So I am reading through a paper called "A coupled finite volume solver for the solution
of incompressible flows on unstructured grids", and this term showed up:

[image]

The authors of the paper did not define this notation and I cannot find what it means anywhere. Does anyone know what they could mean by this? The mdotf is referring to a mass flow rate by the way. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It usually represents the Euclidean norm (magnitude) of a vector.

Comment: @Laufen, the norm of a vector would be with a single element between those $|| . ||$